# Networks Project Related to Foursquare/Instagram

Tags: facebook, social-networking, foursquare, instagram, complex-networks

I'm looking to do a complex networks (Small World, Betweenness, Likeliness of Checking in, etc) project on Foursquare or Instagram. My minimum requirement is 300 Nodes.

However, I'm not sure with the propose as to what analysis can be done on these networks, i.e. what data can be collected, how, and what analysis can be done (like what questions can be answered). Also, Like FB restricts the API to only users, ie, I can use the API only with my user account, I wanna know if there are restrictions like these on Foursquare or Instagram.

Please help me out as I'm short on time and need to decide on my project ASAP.

PS: I know this is not a "coding" question. But is related to networks and this is where most devs are. So I thought I'd ask you guys for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foursquare API to get information about users and venues. You can access the venues API without any user authentication, but to get user information you will need to authenticate on behalf of a user. The documentation is available here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/